# 500 Internal Server Error From PHP - Insert Data Into VFP9 Database

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to write an API script in PHP to insert records into a Foxpro 9 database but i'm getting the "500 Internal Server Error" message when the API is called. I'm a Foxpro developer but pretty new to PHP.

I've gone through several questions & comments on the topic on this site and other sites and have implemented almost all of the suggested solutions to no avail. Below are the steps i've taken so far:

1. IIS & PHP are installed and configured. (phpinfo() is displaying correctly)
2. VFP 9 is fully installed. (with VFPOLEDB driver)
3. I've fully cleared browsing data severally.

I'm not sure where the problem is (as the "500 internal server error" message could be a problem with the PHP script or PHP configuration. Could somebody please take a look at the PHP script below to help figure out the problem?

TIA.

```
<?php 
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// database connection
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$conn->Open("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sonreceipt\RECEIPT.DBC;Collating Sequence=Machine");

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set payment values received
$jrefnum = $data->refnum;
$jpaydate = $data->paydate;
$jcustname = $data->custname;
$jcustemail = $data->custemail;
$jdemandno = $data->demandno;
$jdemanddate = $data->demanddate;
$jamount = $data->amount;
$jrecpdesc = $data->recpdesc;
$jpaybank = $data->paybank;
$jpayref = $data->payref;

// create the payment
if(create()){
    echo "Payment was created.";
} 

// if unable to create the payment, tell the user
else {
    echo "Unable to create payment.";
}

// create payment
function create(){

   // query to insert record
    $query = "INSERT INTO SON2100 (refnum, paydate, custname, custemail, demandno, demanddate, amount, recpdesc, paybank, payref)  
                VALUES ($srefnum, $spaydate, $scustname, $scustemail, $sdemandno, $sdemanddate, $smount, $srecpdesc, $spaybank, $spayref)";

    // prepare query
    global $conn
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    // sanitize
    global $jrefnum, $jpaydate, $jcustname, $jcustemail, $jdemandno, $jdemanddate, $jamount, $jrecpdesc, $jpaybank, $jpayref;
    $srefnum=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jrefnum));
    $spaydate=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jpaydate));
    $scustname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jcustname));
    $scustemail=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jcustemail));
    $sdemandno=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jdemandno));
    $sdemanddate=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jdemanddate));
    $samount=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jamount));
    $srecpdesc=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jrecpdesc));
    $spaybank=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jpaybank));
    $spayref=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jpayref));

    // execute query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    } 

    return false;
}
?>
```

Below is the javascript that calls the API.

```
<script>
function sendData(data) {
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var jsonData = {"refnum":"1111-2222-3333", "paydate":"01-06-2018", "custname":"O. A. BECKLEY VENTURES", "custemail":"beckleyventures@gmail.com", "demandno":"DEMAND NOTE 001", "demanddate":"01-06-2018", "amount":"15550.00", "recpdesc":"SONCAP", "paybank":"ZENITH BANK PLC", "payref":"0123456789"};

    // Define what happens on successful data submission
    XHR.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
        window.alert('Yeah! Data sent and response loaded.');
    });

    // Define what happens in case of error
    XHR.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
        window.alert('Oops! Something goes wrong.');
    });

    // Set up our request
    XHR.open('POST', 'http://localhost/sonreceipt/api/create_payment.php', true);

    // Add the required HTTP header for form data POST requests
    XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    // Finally, send our data.
    XHR.send(jsonData);
}
</script>
```

Here is the edited script but still not working. As indicated earlier, i'm still new to PHP.

```
<?php 

// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// database connection
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");

try {
    $conn->Open('Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;DSN=RECEIPT;Mode=ReadWrite;Password="";Collating Sequence=MACHINE;');
    if (! $conn) {
       throw new Exception("Could not connect!");
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error (File:): ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
}

if (!$conn)
    {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
echo "Connection Sucessfull";

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set payment values received
$jrefnum = $data->refnum;
$jpaydate = $data->paydate;
$jcustname = $data->custname;
$jcustemail = $data->custemail;
$jdemandno = $data->demandno;
$jdemanddate = $data->demanddate;
$jamount = $data->amount;
$jrecpdesc = $data->recpdesc;
$jpaybank = $data->paybank;
$jpayref = $data->payref;

// create the payment
if(create()){
    echo "Payment was created.";
} 

// if unable to create the payment, tell the user
else {
    echo "Unable to create payment.";
}

// create payment
function create(){

    global $conn;
    global $jrefnum, $jpaydate, $jcustname, $jcustemail, $jdemandno, $jdemanddate, $jamount, $jrecpdesc, $jpaybank, $jpayref;

    // sanitize
    $srefnum=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jrefnum));
    $spaydate=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jpaydate));
    $scustname=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jcustname));
    $scustemail=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jcustemail));
    $sdemandno=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jdemandno));
    $sdemanddate=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jdemanddate));
    $samount=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jamount));
    $srecpdesc=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jrecpdesc));
    $spaybank=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jpaybank));
    $spayref=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($jpayref));

   // query to insert record
    $query = "INSERT INTO SON2100 (refnum, paydate, custname, custemail, demandno, demanddate, amount, recpdesc, paybank, payref) 
      VALUES ($srefnum, $spaydate, $scustname, $scustemail, $sdemandno, $sdemanddate, $smount, $srecpdesc, $spaybank, $spayref)";

   // prepare query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    // execute query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    } 

    return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: It means something isn't parsing in your script

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the variables used in the `value` portion of the SQL in your `create()` function and you're missing a semicolon

```
//  you have
global $conn

// should be
global $conn ;
```

Comment: I've made the corrections you noted but still not working. I've also placed the following line at the start of the script.

Comment: echo "PHP Script Started!"; Still not working. This seems to indicate that the php script is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to find your error.

Comment: I've placed the 3 lines of code at the top of the php script, but it's still not working. The 500 internal server error is still coming up.

Comment: At this point, i thing the problem could be with the configuration of php ( i may be wrong!). Even though phpinfo() is displaying when called from the browser. I need to get this script working asap.

Comment: Yes, the 3 lines of code to find the error are now working and I've been able to troubleshoot to an extent. Now, the problem is with the database query. This is the error message from php: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught com_exception: <b>Source:</b> ADODB.Connection<br/><b>Description:</b> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SonReceipt\api\create_test.php:67
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SonReceipt\api\create_test.php(67): com->prepare('INSERT INTO SON2100...')

Comment: This is the database query in the php file: `    $query = "INSERT INTO SON2100 (refnum, paydate, custname, custemail, demandno, demanddate, amount, recpdesc, paybank, payref) 
   VALUES ($srefnum, $spaydate, $scustname, $scustemail, $sdemandno, $sdemanddate, $samount, $srecpdesc, $spaybank, $spayref)";`